# Fisheye effect in GameMaker Ray Casting

Tags: raycasting, game-maker, fisheye, game-maker-studio-2

I've recently made an easy ray caster in Game maker just with a 2d game where you walk and collide with walls and then i added a ray caster to it:

```
function cast_ray(sx, sy, sdir) {
    var rayx=sx
    var rayy=sy
    
    while true {
        if collision_point(rayx, rayy, obj_wall, false, true) or rayx<0 or rayx>room_width or rayy<0 or rayy>room_height {
            break
        }
        
        rayx+=lengthdir_x(1, sdir)
        rayy+=lengthdir_y(1, sdir)
    }
    
    return [point_distance(sx, sy, rayx, rayy), [rayx, rayy]]
}
```

This fires a ray and continues it until it touches a wall or exits the game room. When that happens, the function returns the length of the ray and it's collision point. I then added a `draw_rays()` function that fires the number of rays that corresponds to the variable `resolution`, gets their length and finally calculates the height they should have on screen (`rotation` corresponds to player rotation):

```
function draw_rays() {
    var rot_start=rotation-resolution/2
    var ray_width=room_width/resolution
    
    for (var r=0;r<resolution;r++) {
        var ray=cast_ray(x, y, rot_start)
        var rayd=ray[0]
        //show_debug_message(rot_start)
        var rayh=clamp(50000/rayd, 0, room_height)
        var col=make_color_rgb(clamp(rayh, 0, 255), clamp(rayh, 0, 255), clamp(rayh, 0, 255))
        
        draw_set_color(col)
        draw_rectangle(r*ray_width, height-rayh/2, r*ray_width+ray_width, height+rayh/2, false)
        rot_start+=1
    }
}
```

[Everything works fine untill you approach a wall:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmnQD.png)

I tried changing one part of my code as everyone was doing to counter this effect (6th line of second code): `var rayd=ray[0]` to `var rayd=ray[0]*cos(degtorad(rotation-rot_start))`.
It worked only for [the walls you are facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0zFk.png)
but the [walls on your side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qR5u.png) got worse

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem with ray casting, as described [here](https://www.permadi.com/tutorial/raycast/rayc8.html).

Should be solvable by doing something like

```
rayd *= dcos(rotation - rot_start);
```

before the `rayh` calculation.